# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer:

Tags: tensorflow, keras

i have a error in following code , error in 2st part on code and on first part i am declaring my dataset , layers etc.

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data=pd.read_excel('/content/dataset.xlsx')
data.head()

data.plot(kind='scatter', x='fiyat', y='yil',alpha = 0.5,color = 'red')
plt.xlabel('price')              # label = name of label
plt.ylabel('year')
plt.title('Fiyat ve yil Scatter Plot') 

data.plot(kind='scatter', x='fiyat', y='km',alpha = 0.5,color = 'grey')
plt.xlabel('price')              # label = name of label
plt.ylabel('km')
plt.title('Fiyat ve km Scatter Plot') 
data.plot(kind='scatter', x='fiyat', y='motor_gucu_hp',alpha = 0.5,color = 'green')
plt.xlabel('price')              # label = name of label
plt.ylabel('machine power')
plt.title('fiyat ve motor_gucu_hp Scatter Plot') 

# Importing the dataset
X = data.iloc[:, data.columns != 'fiyat']
y = data.fiyat

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# define base model
def baseline_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=120, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(120, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(120, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='mse',
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['mae'] )
    return model

model = baseline_model()
model.summary()
```

> And getting error in here ; on model.fit location

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np


# Display training progress by printing a single dot for each completed epoch
EPOCHS = 500

# Store training stats
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=EPOCHS,
                    batch_size=16, verbose=0)
```

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 120 but received input with shape (None, 47)

And error like this , can you help? What can i do.

Comment: Change `input_dim = 120` to `input_dim = 47`.

Comment: Did you tried as suggested above?